# How to pass a value in a function and put the function in a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, function

I want to create a cpp program that will have two functions.

```
void func(int num){
 //Assume there are contents here
}

int main(){
    int num;
    cin >> num
    ap(num);
}
```

The code above works when executed. But I want to use my function `func(int num)` in a thread.

```
thread t1(func);
t1.join;
```

When I use my func() in a thread, in no longer executes. That is why I cannot proceed coding my second function. What is the proper way of passing the value to a function so it can be used in a thread?

Comment: Read a file and display the contents.  Use one thread for reading, another for writing.  Share a buffer or two between the threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to take a look at this link:  https://www.tutorialcup.com/cplusplus/multithreading.htm
It has many examples and lots of theory to read and understand about threads and multithreading.